# Is there a way to take integrals over changing variables? Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, integral

I am trying to take the (integral from x to b/2 of pz(zeta) d(zeta)) which is the shear force due to lift and the -(integral from x to b/2 of (zeta-x)*pz(zeta) d(zeta)) which is the moment due to lift

```
% Create a spanwise distance vector
x = linspace(0, b/2, 100);

% Calculate lift distribution pz(x)
pz = p0 * sqrt(1 - (x / (b/2)).^2);

% Preallocate arrays for shear force and moment distributions
Vz_lift = zeros(size(x));
My_lift = zeros(size(x));

% Calculate shear force and moment distributions
for i = 1:length(x)
    Vz_lift(i) = trapz(x(i:end), pz(i:end), 2);
    My_lift(i) = -trapz(x(i:end), (x(i:end) - x(i)) .* pz(i:end),2);
end`

% Plot shear force distribution
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(x, Vz_lift);
xlabel('Spanwise Distance (x)');
ylabel('Shear Force Distribution (N)');
title('Shear Force Distribution due to Lift over Half Span');

% Plot moment distribution
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(x, My_lift);
xlabel('Spanwise Distance (x)');
ylabel('Moment Distribution (N*m)');
title('Moment Distribution due to Lift over Half Span');
```

The resulting moment and shear force graphs don't look right to me. Am I taking the integrals correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong with it.
In cases like this, a good approach can be to try out a simpler problem where you know the solution (or can calculate it analytically). You could for example take something like `pz = p0*x;` as a test case.

But to answer your question in the title - the way you're performing the integration is very inefficient and will quickly become a problem if you ever intend to increase the resolution. In fact, for each x you're recomputing the solution for all previous values of x. Matlab has indeed a built-in function for this type of numerical integration called [cumtrapz](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html) which will run much faster. Below is a comparison of the time it takes on my system to compute your integrands for varying numbers of points N with your method and with cumtrapz.

[image]